# Shadow with low resolution in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to solve the pixelated shadow problem (see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oxn5.png)). This only happens when I build for Android. The further away the object is from the origin of the coordinates, the more pixelated its shadow becomes. I have looked in several forums, but I haven't found a definitive solution. I tried all kinds of shadow and quality settings. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

That could have something to do with the camera clip far planes, but more than likely, you'll have to use projectors to get the job done, since Android shadows are often SIGNIFICANTLY different:

[Unity Shadow Projector Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html)

Comment: I saw that using Projector is not recommended for mobile because it is a bit heavy. But I'll see if it works. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Indeed, try and profile it and see how it works out. You can also try flattening a simple mesh on the ground, or just simply doing a fake blob (fake projector), like bgolus mentions here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/which-is-more-cpu-expensive-blob-shadows-or-the-default-shadows.514830/#post-3372899

Comment: Using the projectors is one of the solutions. The other one I found is here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1217102/shadows-are-ugly-pixelated-after-an-android-build.html